# How to host a large database

Tags: database, size

I am a beginner and I am having some trouble finding a way to host a  large database.
It is a 38gb database in SQL.
There is only one table in that database (column id, column surface and column coordinates) with approx 90M rows.

The end goal of the site is that the user type the id and/or surface and the site will return the coordinates.

At first I was naively thinking that I could just use a regular web hosting service but their database are often limited to 5-10gb.

Then I heard about sharding but I don't even know if it's possible in my case.

And finally I heard about dedicated hosting but from what I found it costs thousands per month, which I can't afford.

It looks like you can "easily" host 2gb database or 2tb database but not in between.

Thanks for reading !

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_.

Comment: @jarlh I am confused. Is this not [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as "asking us to recommend or find ... off-site resource"?

Comment: @AndreyBienkowski, probably it is. (At least I voted so.)

Comment: @colducra this question is likely to be closed as off-topic. See the link I posted above.

Comment: @jarlh I was confused because you (a much more experienced user than me) edited the question. To me it appeared to indicate that you think it is on-topic.

Comment: @AndreyBienkowski, out of sight, out of mind.